# Forcing a JPanel to repaint after calling the show method of CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, repaint, cardlayout

I'm writing a holiday recommendation system for a piece of coursework. The GUI of which uses CardLayout. In the main class a user object is created with default name and access levels defined in it's constructor. this object is passed from main to the UserCard panel which passes it to Login and logged in.
if the user successfully logs in then the cardpanel transitions from Login to logged in and is supposed to display the username of the logged in user by calling the user.getUsername(); method.

my problem is thus. because of the way card layout works the panel with the username display has already been created in the constructor of UserCards with the default values from then the user object was first created. I need to find a way to force this panel to repaint after the show method is called on the cardlayout object. The following is the code of the 3 classes in question. (I've limited the code paste to the relevant methods).

```
//the usercards panel

        public UserCards(User u)
    {
        CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
        this.setLayout(cl);

        UserOptionsPanel options_card = new UserOptionsPanel(cl, this);
        RegisterPanel register_card = new RegisterPanel(cl, this);
        LoggedInPanel loggedin_card = new LoggedInPanel(cl, this, u);
        LoginPanel login_card = new LoginPanel(cl, this, u, loggedin_card);

        this.add(options_card, options);
        this.add(login_card, login);
        this.add(register_card, register);
        this.add(loggedin_card, loggedin);
    }

//the Loggin action listener user is passed in as a reference to the user object created in //main. the createUser(); method is a badly named method that simply calls setter methods on //the user object's fields

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        String[] vals = packData();
        try
        {
            DBConnection d = new DBConnection();
            Connection conn = d.getConnection();
            Validation v = new Validation(vals, user);
            v.getActual(conn);
            if(v.validate())
            {
                user = v.createUser();
                System.out.println(user.getUserName());
                l.revalidate();
                cl.show(pane, "loggedin");
            }
            else
            {
                lbl_statusmsg.setText("Password Incorrect");
                lbl_statusmsg.repaint();
            }

        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

//the loggedin constructor

public class LoggedInPanel extends JPanel
{
    private User user;
    private JLabel lbl_details;
    public LoggedInPanel(CardLayout cl, Container pane, User u)
    {
        super();
        user = u;
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        lbl_details = new JLabel();
        lbl_details.setText("Welcome "+user.getUserName());

        this.add(lbl_details);
    }    
}
```

Apologies if I've not been overly clear I'm not given to asking for help :)

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable,

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like ?

```
CardLayout cl = new CardLayout() {
  @Override
  public void show(java.awt.Container parent, String name) {
    super.show(parent, name);
    // your code here

  }
};
```

Comment: login requires database access so that's not really possible without a fairly extensive rewrite I'm afraid (mostly because my university saw fit to slap 4 layers of security between me an their MySQL installation)

Comment: @user2182380 yes, you can try adding repaint there.